# Splitting string with string C# .net 1.1.4322

Tags: c#, split, .net-1.1

How do I split a string with a string in C# .net 1.1.4322?

String example:

```
Key|Value|||Key|Value|||Key|Value|||Key|Value
```

need:

```
Key|Value
Key|Value
Key|Value
```

- I cannot use the RegEx.Split because the separating character is the ||| and just get every character separately.
- I cannot use the String.Split() overload as its not in .net 1.1

**Example of Accepted solution:**

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

String[] values = Regex.Split(stringToSplit,"\\|\\|\\|");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using @"\|\|\|" in your Regex.Split call? That makes the | characters literal characters.

Answer (score 3):

One workaround is replace and split:

```
string[] keyvalues = "key|value|||key|value".replace("|||", "~").split('~');
```

Comment: And what happens if the original string has a `~` in it somewhere?

Comment: `~` is just an example. You could use any character, but this certainly is not a perfect workaround.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example:

```
System.Collections.Hashtable table;
string[] items = somestring.split("|||");
foreach(string item in items)
{
   string[] keyvalue = item.split("|");
   table.add(keyvalue[0],keyvalue[1]);
}
```

Comment: `Split(string, StringCompareOptions)` and `Split(string, Int32, StringCompareOptions)` didn't appear until .NET Framework 2.0. OP specified 1.1

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "Hi#*#Hello#*#i#*#Hate#*#My#*#......" ;
string[] delim = new string[] { "#*#" };
string[] results = input.split(delim , StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: The question is about .NET 1.1. The overload of `string.Split` accepting a `string[]` has been added in .NET 2.0